# Catch all errors in Sails while submitting form

Tags: node.js, validation, error-handling, sails.js

Hey I am new to Sails I am having an issue while submitting form when in my model username and email is set to unique in my input field if I put username and email which already exist in database I am just getting error for unique username not for email if I fix username then I will get error for email but I want both errors to be shown at one go

Here is the model code:

```
 username: {
            type: "string",
            required: true,
            unique: true,
        },
        name: {
            type: "string",
            required: true,
        },
        title: {
            type: "string",
        },
        email: {
            type: "string",
            isEmail: true,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
        },
        password: {
            type: "string",
            minLength: 6
        },
```

This is controller code

````
var result=await Users.create(req.allParams(),function(err,data){
           if(err)
           {
                 console.log(err);
           }
           else
           {
                 console.log(data)
           }

        });```
````

Comment: What's teh error you get ?

Answer (score 0):

your controller should be like

```
module.exports = {
    create: async (req, res) => {

      //get your params and body using req.params or req.body

     try {

       //controller's logic here
       let user = await Users.create(data).fetch();
        res.status(200)
           .send({ user })

     } catch (error) {

       //catch all errors here 
       res.status(500)
          .send({ err:error })
    }
  },
```